# Start and end time of a query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

As part of the requirements for a stored procedure, I need to provide the start and end time of a particular sub-query. For example, let's say that my query is:

```
SELECT  price
  FROM  vehicles
  WHERE wheels < 3
```

The output of my stored procedure should be a refcursor that points to a table like:

```
price  start_time          end_time
12000  2018-08-08 08:42:31 2018-08-08 08:42:52
130000 2018-08-08 08:42:31 2018-08-08 08:42:52
6000   2018-08-08 08:42:31 2018-08-08 08:42:52
3500   2018-08-08 08:42:31 2018-08-08 08:42:52
```

where `start_time` is the time I started the select statement, and `end_time` is the time it completed.

I've tried the following:

```
WITH start_time AS
( SELECT sysdate AS start_time
    FROM dual
), main_query AS
( SELECT  price
    FROM  vehicles
    WHERE wheels < 3
), end_time AS
( SELECT sysdate AS end_time
    FROM dual
)
SELECT       main_query.*
     ,       TO_CHAR(start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS start_time
     ,       TO_CHAR(end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS end_time
  FROM       main_query
  CROSS JOIN start_time
  CROSS JOIN end_time
;
```

But both start_time and end_time say the same time.

I know this is an unconventional (and clunky) requirement, but needs must...

Comment: SYSDATE refers always to the moment when you run (i.e. start) the query. You must either run additional queries or make a trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results of functions `systimestamp` and `sysdate` are being cached when you use them in `SQL`, so they always return a moment when the query has started.

Create custom function `my_timestamp` without caching, so it would be called once per fetching each row. And consider that `sysdate` has second precision, so there's a chance to miss a time gap on blazing fast queries. That's why `systimestamp` is more useful for benchmarking.

Depending on how it's going to be used, sometimes it's important to apply `/*+ materialize */` hint to ensure that the query executed the only time, otherwise on small result sets optimizer could decide to run the subquery several times making time results inconsistent.

```
with
  function my_timestamp return timestamp is begin return systimestamp; end;

  main_query AS (      
    SELECT /*+ materialize */
      my_timestamp AS custom_ts, 
      systimestamp AS standard_ts,
      T.* 
    FROM vehicles T  
  )  
select (select max(custom_ts) from main_query) as end_time,
       (select min(custom_ts) from main_query) as begin_time,
       T.*
from main_query T;
```

PS. Also, take [a look at](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73253) `dbms_utility.get_time` function for measuring time of code execution.

Answer (score 4):

If part of a procedure, let it handle in two parts. First we get the data, then we return it.

We create an object to store the data temporarily:

```
create type r_price_index as object (
    price  number(10,2));
create type t_price_index is table of r_price_index;
```

Then in your proc:

```
declare
v_price_index t_price_index;
v_t_stamp1    date;
v_t_stamp2    date;
v_cur         sys_refcursor;
v_out         sys_refcursor;

begin

v_t_stamp := sysdate; -- The start time

open v_cur for
  SELECT  price
  FROM  vehicles
  WHERE wheels < 3;
fetch v_cure bulk collect into v_price_index; -- Store the data in the object
close v_cur;
v_t_stamp2 := sysdate; -- The end time

open v_out for -- Output the stored data
  select price, v_t_stamp1 as s_time, v_t_stampt2 as e_time
  from table(v_price_index);
end;
```

You'll want to put in some exception handling (no_data_found, etc), but this should give you exactly what you're looking for.